# what is the api to activate BLN in samsung galaxy S with BLN kernel modificaiton?

Tags: android, galaxy, backlight

I want to create an application that will give a notification to the user on a specific event. it should be back light notification like BLN control is using. can someone tell me how to turn the light on - assuming I have the correct kernel modification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API for it. Neldar uses directly the kernel modifications to get it. BLN are then managed from services.jar. Your best bet is to study both the kernel patches and the services.jar, or contacting Neldar himself at xda.